# spring data couchbase client ssl supprt

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

we have requirement to implement ssl communication between couchbase client and couchbase clusters. I am using spring data couchbase client api to interact with couchbase cluster, the problem with this api I did not find any property to enable ssl on couchbase client, can you please help me out to configure ssl on couchbase client.

Answer (score 0):

the current spring-data-couchbase version runs against the 1.4 Java SDK, which is not able to work with encrypted communication.

The 2.0 SDK can do that, and we are currently in the process of migrating spring-data-couchbase to the new SDK. For now if you want to use it you most likely need to wire up your own beans with the new SDK.